# Codeigniter-HMVC framework is not accepting directory name under controllers with same name as of controller's name on same level

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-hmvc

Codeigniter-HMVC framework is not accepting directory name under controllers with same name as of controller's name on same level.

```
modules
    ->my_module
        ->contollers  
            -> level1_controller.php
            -> level1_controller
                   -> level2_controller.php
```

URL: `[my Domain]/my_module/level1_controller/level2_controller`
returns 404 error, as it is looking for method name `level2_controller` in `level1_controller.php`

Is this just a limitation of HMVC or i'm doing it in wrong way? Is there any way that I can make HMVC to understand directory name same as of controller's name on same level?

Comment: You may need to set routes for the sub folders but make sure also new version of codeigniter and hmvc that controller file name Level2_controller.php first letter all ways upper case.

Comment: And also have you tried with index.php `http://www.example.com/index.php/my_module/level1_controller/level2_controller`

Comment: yes index.php is part of domain name. I did change First letter to be upper case of controllers, but no change. I wish to make any changes on the HMVC itself so that I can follow same standard for other modules as well. So want to avoid routing on project level